# Question regarding proving $(X,d)$ to be a metric space where $X$ is non-empty set and $d$ is a mapping from $X\times X$ to $\Bbb{R}$ defied below.

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

Firstly, I regret I can't put the full question in the title part due to character limit. The actual question looks like-

> Let, $X$ be a set of all sequences $x=\{x_n\}$ of real numbers and for
>   $x=\{x_n\}$ and $y=\{y_n\}$ of $X$ with $x\ne y$, put
>   $M(x,y)=$min$\{n\in\Bbb{N} : x_n\ne y_n\}$. For any $x, y\in X$,
>   define $$d(x,y) =\begin{cases} 0, & \text{if}\ x=y\\ {1 \over M(x,y)},
>  & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

It is easy to verify that $d(x,y)\ge 0$, $d(x,y)=d(y,x)\;\forall x,y\in X$ and $d(x,y)=0$ if and only if $x=y$.
So, I have to prove $d(x,z)\le d(x,y)+d(z,y)\ \forall x,z,y\in X\tag{1}\label{eq1}$
Choose $x=\{x_n\},\ y=\{y_n\},\ z=\{z_n\}\in X$
If any two of them are equal then $\eqref{eq1}$ follows directly. Similarly if all of them are equal then it is also obvious.
Assume, $x, y, z$ are the there different sequences.
Let, $M(x,z)=p,\ M(x,y)=q,\ M(z,y)=r$. 
My assumption is(not sure) both of $q,r\le p$.
But I cannot write down the proof in a rigorous manner.
Can anybody give me a proper way out for my problem? Thanks for your assistance in advance.

Comment: Try to prove $p \ge \min\{q,r\}$. Once that is done, prove that from this follows the triangle inequality in your metric. Note that $p \ge q,r$ cannot generally be true, as at this point your conditions are symmetric in $x,y$ and $z$.

Comment: @Ingix, can you give me an example where min$\{q,r\}\le p <$max$\{q,r\}$.

Comment: $x_n =\{1,2,3,\ldots\}, y_n=\{1,2,4,\ldots\}, z_n=\{2,3,4,\ldots\}$. We have $p=1, q=3, r=1$.

Comment: @Ingix, suppose $q<r$ and $q<p<r$, then $M(x,z)=p\implies x_q=z_q$ as $q<p$. Again, $M(x,y)=q\implies x_q\ne y_q$ and $M(z,y)=r\implies z_q=y_q$ as $q<r$. Now, $x_q\ne y_q$ and $z_q=y_q$ together imply $x_q\ne z_q$, contradiction. Am I right?

Comment: @Ingix, in your example you had to take $p$ and $r$ to be same. Even can you obeserve in your example the condition $p\ge q,r$ is not violated?

Comment: You can check that the smallest value of $p,q,r$ cannot appear only once, it must appear at least twice. That's why $q < p < r$ leads to a contradiction.

Comment: You wrote: "Even can you obeserve in your example the condition $p \ge q,r$ is not violated?" Maybe this is misunderstanding of meaning. To me $p \ge q,r$ means that both $p \ge q$ and $p \ge r$ must be true. In my example with $p=1, q=3$, $p \ge q$ is certainly not true.

Comment: Sorry, I have made mistake while reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the notation from the problem, it holds that $p \ge \min\{q,r\}$.
Proof: If $q$ or $r$ are equal to 1, that's obvious. If both are greater, let $s=\min\{q,r\}$. We know that for indices $i=1,2,\ldots,s-1: x_i=y_i$ and $z_i=y_i$, because of the definition of $q$ and $r$ and the definiton of $M(a,b)$. So we get $x_i=z_i$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,s-1$, which means $p=M(x,z) \ge s$.$\blacksquare$

Remark: It can be easily shown that if $q \neq r$ then $p=\min\{q,r\}$.

To prove the triangle inequality needed for $d$ to be a metric (under the assumption $x,y$ and $z$ are mutually different), we simply remark that with $s=\min\{q,r\}$:

$$d(x,z) = \frac1p \le \frac1s < \frac1q + \frac1r = d(x,y) + d(y,z)$$

The sharp inequality follows from the fact that the left hand side ($\frac1s$) is one of the two summands on the right hand side, while the other is positive.